# Securing Web API with Oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-filters

Use case:
I have to create a web app (ASP.NET MVC) whose RDBMS is Oracle. The DB already exist with a set of users/roles which are granted to perform certain actions over tables, view an so on. Therefore, there is Security implemented already.
The scope of the web app is for internal usage, thus should be an Intranet. In that, I should not provide a login page since I could get the user from the browser. 
Considering I already have security implemented on the Oracle side, how do I inherit it and apply it into my app? In other words:

### If I have in Oracle:

- Database (D)
- User (U)
- Role (R), where U has role R
- Table (T), where R is granted to SELECT and INSERT on T

### And I have in ASP.NET MVC

- DbContext (DContext) for (D)
- Model (TModel) for (T)
- Controller (TController) with CRUD action methods for (TModel).

How do I add the existing Oracle security to actions mentioned above?

Initially I thought I could decorate the actions with [Authorize] attribute. However, I don't know how to negotiate a Windows credential with Oracle, so that Windows user (X) => Oracle user (U). Therefore, if you try to Update or Delete a TModel, it should return an insufficient privilege exception, as U is not allowed to either update or delete.

I wish someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can auth using SSO in .NET, and then log to Oracle with associated Oracle UID, this way you won't need to deal with Win<>Ora handshake.

Comment: Unless oracle is SSO you will need to accept the users oracle password somewhere... Do you have the ability to set up SSO on your Oracle instance?  I _think_ the securities can run in parallel...

Comment: An alternative approach is to set up a property on the AD containers to hold your users' respective Oracle account details and obtain that in your app

Comment: thank you all for sharing. what about [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/admnauth.htm#i1006459)